# Weird difference in Average Monthly Searches for google keyword planner

Tags: seo, google, google-ads, google-keyword-tool

In this image:

[image]

When I search keyword "lawyers in japan" it says in the blue bars that it had 3,310 Average monthly searches in June as you can see in the mid right section.

Then in the section in the bottom it says that for the same keyword the Average monthly searches where just 30.

I'm very confused as to what is the real Average monthly searches ???

Comment: The number in bar graph is sum of all the keywords listed below that Google thinks are closely related to this term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3,310 result is for all keywords which is suggestion in keyword planner below keywords.

While 30 is the perfect keyword average search result.

Solution:
Filter by below steps:

1. Go to "keyword option" (left side option)
2. Click on edit button of "keyword option"
3. Go to 1st option : "Only show ideas closely related to my search terms"
4. And "ON" this option and click on save.

Now you can see perfect result.